# 401k to lower tax burden without matching contribution

Tags: consultants

Employer has suggested to opt for 401k to lower tax burden. I am on work H1b and my employer is not matching contribution. Should go for 401k or not?

Comment: And the question is.... ??

Comment: Why would an employer care about your tax burden? That's between you and your accountant.

Comment: The question is what should i do? Is it worth to enrolled? As I most of the answers depends on employer contribution but in my case it's not.

Comment: I got suggestion from accounting department of my employer. I am new to this country and learning about tax system.

Comment: It really boils down to this: if you plan on staying in the US until retirement, or at least living in a country where you will need to fund your own retirement and you will have easy access to the US financial system, it makes sense for most people to contribute. If you'll be leaving the US before retirement and moving back to a country with strong social programs and government-supported retirement, you don't really need to.

Comment: Thanks @dwizum for giving clear view on investment. It really matter where I will be at the time of retirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Money you put into a 401(k) plan is tax deferred. It will be invested with a US-based investment firm of your employer's choice. (Vanguard, Fidelity, Schwab, or the like.)  When you reach retirement age you may withdraw it. Many people take a monthly payment. You will be liable for US income tax and state income tax on the money you withdraw just as if it were salary.

The benefit to you: because your 401(k) money is not taxed before you invest it, you can invest more money and accumulate savings faster. The exponential nature of compound interest can be a great benefit.  And, the investment gains your money makes are not subject to tax, except at the time you withdraw them. No taxes on capital gains or interest payments, just on the money you withdraw.

You'll pay less money in taxes today. But you'll also take home less money today. Your pay stub will show the money your employer sent to your 401(k) account.

If you must withdraw your money from your 401(k) account before retirement, you will pay a painful penalty.  Some, but not all, 401(k) tax plans allow you to borrow money from your balance, without penalty, as if it were a loan. Ask your HR person about that.

You can "roll over" your money from one investment firm to another upon leaving a job, without any penalty. If you work at several different jobs during your career, it's wise to roll over each company's 401(k) balance into one single account at one investment firm. That way your retirement money is in one place, rather than scattered in several different accounts at different firms.

Is this a good idea for you?  Probably.  But you will need to figure out how to withdraw the money after retirement.  Can you ask somebody from your native country how that works if you are there and your money is in the US?

Take care not to lose contact with the investment firm or firms holding your money; you must be diligent about informing them of changes to your address, for the rest of your life.  If they can't contact you for some years, they may suspend your account. It's a hassle to get it unsuspended.

Comment: Thank you @Jones for detail answer. It helps me to communicate with HR.